# replacing multiple items in a string with str_replace

Tags: php, str-replace

I have to alter two things in this example text:

`example_1,example_2`

I need to appear this way:
`example 1, example 2`

So I need to replace the "_" with a space " " as well as the "," to ", " with a space. 
Currently I have this code below and it replaces the underscore fine, but I don't know how to also integrate the "," part in this code.

```
str_replace('_', ' ', $test)
```

Would it be something like this:

```
str_replace(('_', ' ',),(',', ' '), $test)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [strtr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) to do multiple replaces simultaneously:

```
strtr($test, array('_' => ' ', ',' => ', '));
```

Answer (score 5):

Or, in one line you can use regex with something similar to:

```
preg_replace("/_(.*)\,/", " \\1, ", "Example_1,Example_2");
```

The code above has a limitation where it won't replace the very last element in your comma-separated list. The following alleviates that problem by making the comma optional using the ? modifier.

```
echo preg_replace("/_(\d)(\,?)/", " \\1\\2 ", "Example_1,Example_2");
```

That expression will now work properly but it should be noted that your final string will probably have a single space character(' ') appended to the end. Not the end of the world but should be noted.

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code, would do the work:

```
$cadena = "example_1,example_2";
$salida = str_replace("_", " ", $cadena);
$salida = str_replace(",", ", ", $salida);

echo $salida;
```

Array version:

```
$buscar = array("_",",");
$reeemplazar = array(" ",", ");
$sal = str_replace($buscar, $reeemplazar, $cadena);

echo $sal;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$str = 'example_1,example_2';

$str = str_replace('_', ' ', $str);

$str = str_replace(',', ', ', $str);
echo $str;
```

check codepad - http://codepad.org/am4L4v91

OR even this works -

```
<?php

$str = 'example_1,example_2';
$match = array('_' =>' ', ',' => ', ');
$str = strtr($str, $match);

echo $str;
```

Check code pad - http://codepad.org/2AI9Pt7x

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is the following:

```
$string = 'example_1,example_2';
$new = str_replace(array('_', ','), array(' ', ', '), $string);
echo $new;
```

Since [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/str-replace) accepts an array.

You could also use regular expressions which is handy when there is unexpected data like this with several spaces:

> example_1, example_2      ,    example_3

```
$string = 'example_1, example_2   , example_3';
$new = preg_replace(array('#_#', '#\s*,\s*#'), array(' ', ', '), $string);
echo $new;
```

Where `\s*` means match 0 or more white spaces.